# rawg.io API call JavaScript to display in html

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

I am still on a quest to figure out JavaScript and working with an API as part of a project I have been set (so still very new to this and only 2 weeks in to learning JS).

I have the API being called fine, I can see the output in network so I know I am getting a connection but despite looking around at ways to do this I am struggling to display the output in my html.

So I have to do this in vanilla js, using async with no `.then` chains etc.

The js I have so far:

```js
async function fetchData() {
    return (await fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=CHANGED_FROM_MY_KEY')).json();
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    let games = [];
    try {
        games = await fetchData();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error!");
        console.log(e);
    }
    console.log(games);
});

function appendData(games) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("rawgGame");
    for (var i = 0; i < games.results; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = 'gameName: ' + games.results[i].name;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = 'gameImage: ' + games.results[i].background_image;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = 'gameRating: ' + games.results[i].metacritic;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
}
window.onload = function appendData() {
    console.log('The games will load now.');
}
```

The output in console :

```
{count: 797560, next: "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=CHANGED_FROM_MY_KEY&page=2",…}
count
: 
797560
description
: 
""
filters
: 
{years: [{from: 2020, to: 2022, filter: "2020-01-01,2022-12-31", decade: 2020,…},…]}
next
: 
"https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=CHANGED_FROM_MY_KEY&page=2"
nofollow
: 
false
nofollow_collections
: 
["stores"]
noindex
: 
false
previous
: 
null
results
: 
[,…]
0
: 
{id: 3498, slug: "grand-theft-auto-v", name: "Grand Theft Auto V", released: "2013-09-17", tba: false,…}
1
: 
{id: 3328, slug: "the-witcher-3-wild-hunt", name: "The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt", released: "2015-05-18",…}
2
: 
{id: 4200, slug: "portal-2", name: "Portal 2", released: "2011-04-18", tba: false,…}
3
: 
{id: 5286, slug: "tomb-raider", name: "Tomb Raider (2013)", released: "2013-03-05", tba: false,…}
4
: 
{id: 4291, slug: "counter-strike-global-offensive", name: "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",…}
5
: 
{id: 5679, slug: "the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim", name: "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim",…}
6
: 
{id: 12020, slug: "left-4-dead-2", name: "Left 4 Dead 2", released: "2009-11-17", tba: false,…}
7
: 
{id: 13536, slug: "portal", name: "Portal", released: "2007-10-09", tba: false,…}
8
: 
{id: 4062, slug: "bioshock-infinite", name: "BioShock Infinite", released: "2013-03-26", tba: false,…}
9
: 
{id: 3439, slug: "life-is-strange-episode-1-2", name: "Life is Strange", released: "2015-01-29",…}
10
: 
{id: 802, slug: "borderlands-2", name: "Borderlands 2", released: "2012-09-18", tba: false,…}
11
: 
{id: 28, slug: "red-dead-redemption-2", name: "Red Dead Redemption 2", released: "2018-10-26",…}
12
: 
{id: 13537, slug: "half-life-2", name: "Half-Life 2", released: "2004-11-16", tba: false,…}
13
: 
{id: 4286, slug: "bioshock", name: "BioShock", released: "2007-08-21", tba: false,…}
14
: 
{id: 1030, slug: "limbo", name: "Limbo", released: "2010-07-21", tba: false,…}
15
: 
{id: 2454, slug: "doom", name: "DOOM (2016)", released: "2016-05-13", tba: false,…}
16
: 
{id: 3070, slug: "fallout-4", name: "Fallout 4", released: "2015-11-09", tba: false,…}
17
: 
{id: 32, slug: "destiny-2", name: "Destiny 2", released: "2017-09-06", tba: false,…}
18
: 
{id: 58175, slug: "god-of-war-2", name: "God of War", released: "2018-04-20", tba: false,…}
19
: 
{id: 11859, slug: "team-fortress-2", name: "Team Fortress 2", released: "2007-10-10", tba: false,…}
seo_description
: 
""
seo_h1
: 
"All Games"
seo_keywords
: 
""
seo_title
: 
"All Games"
```

My thinking (again, very new to this so I am only just getting a grasp of how to work with JS) is that my first function is requesting the API JSON and logging errors or displaying the JSON. The the second function is taking that data and appending it into my html but breaking down the individual sections I want to display in their own child div so I can style them later.

I'm sure there's a much easier and more elegant way to do this but even this method doesn't seem to put anything into my html. Clearly I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

For some reason I just seem to keep hitting a wall with JS, I can look at functions and figure out what they do a little at least, but something with fetch is just not making it much further than my eyes and sinking in.

I am seeing the console.log of The Games will load now and none of the code is showing an error so my guess is how I am trying to specify and display the different fields is wrong.

To expand on the API, just in case there's something very obvious with what I am asking it to do:

```
{count: 797560, next: "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=5faa65d741d94e78b1e567a0a1fc580c&page=2",…}
count
: 
797560
description
: 
""
filters
: 
{years: [{from: 2020, to: 2022, filter: "2020-01-01,2022-12-31", decade: 2020,…},…]}
next
: 
"https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=5faa65d741d94e78b1e567a0a1fc580c&page=2"
nofollow
: 
false
nofollow_collections
: 
["stores"]
noindex
: 
false
previous
: 
null
results
: 
[,…]
0
: 
{id: 3498, slug: "grand-theft-auto-v", name: "Grand Theft Auto V", released: "2013-09-17", tba: false,…}
added
: 
18001
added_by_status
: 
{yet: 456, owned: 10505, beaten: 4950, toplay: 527, dropped: 910, playing: 653}
background_image
: 
"https://media.rawg.io/media/games/456/456dea5e1c7e3cd07060c14e96612001.jpg"
clip
: 
null
dominant_color
: 
"0f0f0f"
esrb_rating
: 
{id: 4, name: "Mature", slug: "mature"}
genres
: 
[{id: 4, name: "Action", slug: "action", games_count: 161519,…},…]
id
: 
3498
metacritic
: 
91
name
: 
"Grand Theft Auto V"
parent_platforms
: 
[{platform: {id: 1, name: "PC", slug: "pc"}},…]
platforms
: 
[{,…},…]
playtime
: 
72
rating
: 
4.47
rating_top
: 
5
ratings
: 
[{id: 5, title: "exceptional", count: 3520, percent: 58.99},…]
ratings_count
: 
5892
released
: 
"2013-09-17"
reviews_count
: 
5967
reviews_text_count
: 
43
saturated_color
: 
"0f0f0f"
short_screenshots
: 
[{id: -1, image: "https://media.rawg.io/media/games/456/456dea5e1c7e3cd07060c14e96612001.jpg"},…]
slug
: 
"grand-theft-auto-v"
stores
: 
[{id: 290375,…}, {id: 438095,…}, {id: 290376,…}, {id: 290377,…}, {id: 290378,…}]
suggestions_count
: 
414
tags
: 
[{id: 31, name: "Singleplayer", slug: "singleplayer", language: "eng", games_count: 182311,…},…]
tba
: 
false
updated
: 
"2022-09-18T09:33:46"
user_game
: 
null
```

Comment: You never call `appendData` (well, you never call the first `appendData` which does the thing you want to do).

Comment: I did try calling appendData() on a previous attempt and got nothing back from it, so I took it back out and posted here in the hope someone will spot simple dumb mistakes I made  :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create multiple `div` elements.

```
                var div
                div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'gameName: ' + games.results[i].name;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);

                div = document.createElement("div");                            
                div.innerHTML = 'gameImage: ' + games.results[i].background_image;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);

                div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'gameRating: ' + games.results[i].metacritic;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
              }
```

You may want to consider creating a parent `div`, and then add child `div` to it, so you can style the parent container.

Also use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`, as you are adding text, not html text.

```js
div.innerText = 'gameName: ' + games.results[i].name;
```

Finally, you need to call your append data function on load.

```
function appendData(
  // code here
}

window.onload = () => {
    console.log('The games will load now.');
    appendData(games)
}
```

One more issue is the case where `onLoad` is called before your async data call resolves.  In that case, `games` will not be set.  A workaround might be to 1. bootstrap the whole data call to start inside of onLoad, or 2. Check for loaded after games is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I have a parent div in the html already 

``
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("rawgGame");
            
```
So for this I would lose trying to wrap the div elements into the function as i already tried,  and just put the var div onward into the function appendData( // code here you suggest? 

I knew I was barking up the right tree but feel like I am throwing things at my screen and hoping they stick rather than understanding it.

Comment: I suggested the container for each item you insert, so they wont all be in the same level.  so a container in a container :)